# rolling forecasts using the R's package rugarch

Tags: r, package

I am using the rugarch package for the estimation of a GARCH's model. I want to get rolling forecasts with a fixed horizon and an estimation's window with fixed size. 
Therefore, I am testing the `ugarchroll` function with parameters as below.

```
rolling<-ugarchroll(specif, variable, n.ahead=1, 
                    n.start=1357, refit.every=1,
                    window.size=1357, 
                    refit.window=c("moving"))
```

When I applied the method `as.data.frame(rolling)`, I get different columns and I would like to know if column "Mu" refers to the conditional mean forecasts?